# VideoCapture with usb camera

Tags: python, opencv

I´m working with C12741-03 Hamamatsu camera conected by USB, i want to control it with OpenCV, with this code i can control the webcam of my computer and a normal USB camera, but hamamatsu camera, what need a API to work and what i have instaled, doesn´t work. I like to know if there are any way to indicate VideoCapture() function the path of the camera or something like that for start the comunication with it. Im working in windows and if you know another library to work with the camera tell me too. Thanks.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if(cap.isOpened()==False):
    print("ERROR AL ABRIR LA CAMARA")

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: maybe providing the error that you're getting with this code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` to `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)`.

Comment: I tried with all numbers and it doesn´t work

Comment: You might need to update your driver's then. Try starting your code editor after the camera has been plugged in